# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter - What does this mean?

Tags: c#

I am trying to call the method but for some reason it wont work 
can someone tell me how to build a better method.

```
namespace ObjectsLifeTime
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Car myCar = new Car();
            myCar.Make = "Ford";
            myCar.Model = "Something";
            myCar.Year = 2010;
            myCar.Colour = "Blue";

            Console.WriteLine(myCar.Stats());

        }


        class Car
        {
            public string Make { get; set; }
            public string Model { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public string Colour { get; set; }

            public static string Stats(Car car)
            {
                string restart = "false";
                do
                {
                    restart = "false";
                    Console.WriteLine("Press a to get the Make of the car");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press s to get the Model of the car");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press d to get the Year of the car");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press f to get the Colour of the car");
                }
                while (restart == "true");
                string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();

                if (UserInput == "a")
                {
                    string UserOutput = car.Make;
                    return UserOutput;
                }
                if (UserInput == "s")
                {
                    string UserOutput = car.Make;
                    return UserOutput;
                }
                if (UserInput == "d")
                {
                    string UserOutput = car.Make;
                    return UserOutput;
                }
                if (UserInput == "f")
                {
                    string UserOutput = car.Make;
                    return UserOutput;
                }
                else
                {
                    restart = "true";
                    string UserOutput = "I did not understand that";
                    return UserOutput;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you explained more what you are doing and what exactly is failing, instead of repeating your text to meet up the character count requirement?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(myCar.Stats());` should likely be `Console.WriteLine(Car.Stats(myCar));`

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to make that change, instead change `public static string Stats(Car car) {` to `public string Stats() { var car = this;`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following code should fix your issue

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Car myCar = new Car();
            myCar.Make = "Ford";
            myCar.Model = "Something";
            myCar.Year = 2010;
            myCar.Colour = "Blue";

            Console.WriteLine(myCar.Stats());
            Console.ReadKey();

        }


        public class Car
        {
            public string Make { get; set; }
            public string Model { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public string Colour { get; set; }

            public  string Stats()
            {
                string restart = "false";
                do
                {
                    restart = "false";
                    Console.WriteLine("Press a to get the Make of the car");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press s to get the Model of the car");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press d to get the Year of the car");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press f to get the Colour of the car");
                }
                while (restart == "true");
                string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();

                if (UserInput == "a")
                {
                    string UserOutput = Make;
                    return UserOutput;
                }
                if (UserInput == "s")
                {
                    string UserOutput = Model;
                    return UserOutput;
                }
                if (UserInput == "d")
                {
                    string UserOutput = Year.ToString();
                    return UserOutput;
                }
                if (UserInput == "f")
                {
                    string UserOutput = Colour;
                    return UserOutput;
                }
                else
                {
                    restart = "true";
                    string UserOutput = "I did not understand that";
                    return UserOutput;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Stats function is static.
If you did it  intentionally then you can access it via the class name Car.Stats()

If you want to access it from each of the instances of the class Car then you need to make a regular function (remove the static...)

Comment: Thanks That helped but what does **static** actually do? could you please put in an example - everywhere I've looked is too vague or over-complicated

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented programming class is a template of something... like car. 
Car is the template but volvo for example is an instance of car. 
volvo was made out of the template of car but it is a single instance of it. 
all of the properties and function defined in the class car can be access threw volvo instance. 
when talking about static what we really want to say is that in some cases we would like to have the ability to use a function or a property with no relation to instance of the class.. let's suppose we have the class car.

in the class car we create a static member named gasPrice

```
public class Car 
{ 
   public static double gasPrice =5;
   public string Make { get; set; } 
   public string Model { get; set; } 
   public int Year { get; set; } 
   public string Colour { get; set; } 
}
```

Now this property is shared between all the instances of car... volvo honda what ever... you cannot edit it only for one of them. 
The value of gasPrice set by the class level... now it צakes sense that we cant access it from one of the instances... 
We can access it only from the class name because it is related to the class!

[link for static explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

Cheers!